# How to avoid repainting when using security()

Tags: pine-script, trading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J24kK.png)I tried to use PineCoders f_secureSecurity code on tradingview to avoid repainting when using security(), for the following code, but still I am getting repainted, could you please help me to understand what is wrong ?

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="archiesma", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

timeFrame = input(title="Other time frame", type=input.resolution, defval="")
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

L = close > open
S = close < open

LongW = f_secureSecurity(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeFrame, L)
ShortW = f_secureSecurity(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeFrame, S)


strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = LongW)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = ShortW)

strategy.close("Long", when = ShortW)
strategy.close("Short", when = LongW)
```

Comment: How do you conclude that the code repaints?

Comment: I am getting repainted error from TV.

Comment: Traders use "repainting" to name many different things. How are you determining that the code repaints?

Comment: I have added a pic to my post, check out the pic please, this is what I mean

Comment: That warning says "may trigger" and the logic triggering it is very conservative. Merely using `bar_index`, for example, will trigger the warning. So don't fret. If you use `f_secureSecurity()` your code will not repaint. Promised.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/amp/s/fr.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/%3famp

First: Search on Google

Second: Ask